Ionic app how to show GIF image starting from first frame
In my ionic app, I have a gif image that I want to show and hide pressing a button, but, when I push the show button, I'd like to show gif image from the first frame. For example, if gif is the countdown 5,4,3,2,1.... I'd like to show always from the number 5. I tried using display:none/display:block, but image shows randomly. Any suggestion?

I creating a new instance of the GIF every time you toggle it, you can simply reset the GIF to its initial frame when showing it again.
HTML CODE:
<img id="gifImage" src="assets/countdown.gif" style="display: none;">
<button (click)="toggleGif()">Toggle GIF</button>

TS code:
 toggleGif() {
    var gifImage = document.getElementById("gifImage");
    if (gifImage) {
        if (gifImage.style.display === "none") {
            // Show gif
            gifImage.style.display = "block";
            // Created gif based new instance time
            (gifImage as HTMLImageElement).src = 'assets/countdown.gif' + "?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime();
        } else {
            // Hide gif
            gifImage.style.display = "none";
        }
    } else {
        console.error("Gif not found");
    }
    }

